Remove all occurences of substring from variable given prefix & suffix of substring
As an example, I have a variable containing:
sentence="\<Name\>Mary\</Name\> has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that \<Name\>Sharon\</Name\> went the lamb was sure to go. \<Name\>Lucy\</Name\>, \<Name\>Mary\</Name\> quite contrary how does your garden grow?"

and I need to remove (all occurences) everything between prefix \<Name\> and suffix \</Name\>, including the prefix and suffix strings themselves to get:
sentence=" has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that  went the lamb was sure to go. ,  quite contrary how does your garden grow?"

I have no clue how to achieve this. Does anyone have a sed, awk, etc solution?

sed -E 's#\\<Name\\>[^\]+\\</Name\\>##g' works for your specific case (assumes \ doesn't appear in between the escaped tags).

Why worry about all of that, sed 's/.*\\>//' removes everything up to the closing ....\>. BUT it probably won't work on real-world data. Good luck!

best way is to use sed as follows:
#!/bin/bash
sentence="<Name>Mary</Name> has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that <Name>Sharon</Name> went the lamb was sure to go. <Name>Lucy</Name>, <Name>Mary</Name> quite contrary how does your garden grow?"

# Use sed to remove everything between <Name> and </Name>, including the tags
cleaned_sentence=$(echo "$sentence" | sed 's/<Name>[^<]*<\/Name>//g')

echo "$cleaned_sentence"

or awk:
#!/bin/bash

sentence="<Name>Mary</Name> has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that <Name>Sharon</Name> went the lamb was sure to go. <Name>Lucy</Name>, <Name>Mary</Name> quite contrary how does your garden grow?"

# Use awk to remove everything between <Name> and </Name>, including the tags
cleaned_sentence=$(echo "$sentence" | awk '{gsub(/<Name>[^<]*<\/Name>/, ""); print}')

echo "$cleaned_sentence"


grep -oP:
#!/bin/bash

sentence="<Name>Mary</Name> has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that <Name>Sharon</Name> went the lamb was sure to go. <Name>Lucy</Name>, <Name>Mary</Name> quite contrary how does your garden grow?"

# Use grep to exclude text between <Name> and </Name> and join lines
cleaned_sentence=$(echo "$sentence" | grep -oP '(?<=<\/Name>).+?(?=<Name>)|(?<=<\/Name>).+$' | tr -d '\n')

echo "$cleaned_sentence"


tr and sed combined:
#!/bin/bash

sentence="<Name>Mary</Name> has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that <Name>Sharon</Name> went the lamb was sure to go. <Name>Lucy</Name>, <Name>Mary</Name> quite contrary how does your garden grow?"

# Replace the <Name> and </Name> tags with a newline character to isolate the parts to be removed
# and then use sed to delete those lines, finally joining everything back together without line breaks
cleaned_sentence=$(echo "$sentence" | tr -s '\n' | sed 's/<Name>/\n<Name>/g' | sed 's/<\/Name>/<\/Name>\n/g' | sed '/<Name>.*<\/Name>/d' | tr -d '\n')

echo "$cleaned_sentence"



Thanks a lot but it's not working for me and I think it is because the string between the prefix/suffix could also contain < or </ and >.  Would you agree and if so, how to work around that?

Yes, Nabin had a good answer. I suggest you accept it (click the checkmark). We answer authors are always grateful for rep tips!

Just a little tip: when passing text to a command as input, you can get rid of the extra echo or printf by writing it as command <<< text.

thank you for the input @Raven, i just shared what i usually do , i will try your method as well and implement.

With bash and its parameter expansion:
sentence="\<Name\>Mary\</Name\> has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that \<Name\>Sharon\</Name\> went the lamb was sure to go. \<Name\>Lucy\</Name\>, \<Name\>Mary\</Name\> quite contrary how does your garden grow?"

# remove all \
sentence="${sentence//\\/}"
while true; do
  if [[ "$sentence" =~ \<Name\>[^\<]*\</Name\> ]]; then
    # remove found substring from variable sentence
    sentence="${sentence/${BASH_REMATCH[0]}/}"
  else
    # leave loop
    break
  fi
done
echo "$sentence"

Output:
 has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that  went the lamb was sure to go. ,  quite contrary how does your garden grow?


Nice to see this version.  Most people forget that Bash has had regular expressions for many years now.

It becomes easy to do if you have access to regular expression supporting non-greedy matching e.g. perl
sentence="\<Name\>Mary\</Name\> has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that \<Name\>Sharon\</Name\> went the lamb was sure to go. \<Name\>Lucy\</Name\>, \<Name\>Mary\</Name\> quite contrary how does your garden grow?"
echo "$sentence" | perl -p -e 's/\\<Name\\>.*?\\<\/Name\\>//g'

gives output
 has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that  went the lamb was sure to go. ,  quite contrary how does your garden grow?

Explanation: -p -e does engage sed mode, \<Name\> and \</Name\> must be escaped therefore additional backslashes, .*? means any character (.) repeated zero-or-more times (*) as few times as possible (?) i.e. non-greedy way.
(tested in perl v5.34.0)

Using a sed that has -E for EREs, e.g. GNU or BSD sed:
$ echo "$sentence" | sed -E 's/\\[<>]/\n/g; s/(\n[^\n]*){3}\n//g'
 has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that  went the lamb was sure to go. ,  quite contrary how does your garden grow?

or any POSIX sed:
$ echo "$sentence" | sed 's/\\[<>]/\n/g; s/\(\n[^\n]*\)\{3\}\n//g'
 has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that  went the lamb was sure to go. ,  quite contrary how does your garden grow?

or GNU awk for multi-char RS:
$ echo "$sentence" | awk -v RS='[\\\\]</?Name[\\\\]>' -v ORS= '(NR-1)%2 == 0'
 has a little lamb it's fleece as white as snow and everywhere that  went the lamb was sure to go. ,  quite contrary how does your garden grow?

